# Can't get angular-socket-io to display messages

Tags: angularjs, socket.io

I have the following declarations in my app.js file:

```
(function () {
    angular.module('medmart', [
        'oc.lazyLoad',
        'ui.bootstrap', 
        'ngFileUpload',
        'ui.validate',
        'btford.socket-io',
    ]).
    factory('mySocket', function (socketFactory) {
        var mySocket = socketFactory({
            prefix: 'medmart~',
            ioSocket: io.connect('https://:::8443'),
        });
        mySocket.forward('error');
        return mySocket;
    });
})();
```

And in my index.html I have the following statements:

`<script src="js/angular/angular.min.js"></script>`
`<script src="js/plugins/oclazyload/dist/ocLazyLoad.min.js"></script>`
`<script src="js/ui-router/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>`
`<script src="js/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.12.0.min.js"></script>`
`<script src="js/plugins/ng-file-upload/ng-file-upload.min.js"></script>`
`<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>`
`<script src="js/plugins/angular-socket-io/socket.js"></script>`

And in controlers.js I have the following:

```
mySocket.forward('medmart~procedure', $scope);

$scope.user = {
    fname: '',
    lname: '',
    pid: ''
};
$scope.setCredentials = function() {    
    $scope.user.fname   = $rootScope.user.fname;
    $scope.user.lname   = $rootScope.user.lname;
    $scope.user.pid     = $rootScope.user.pid;
};
$scope.setCredentials();

mySocket.on('connect', function () {

    $scope.$on('socket:error', function (ev, data) {
        console.log("ERROR: " + data)
    });
    $scope.$on('medmart~procedure', function(event, data) {

        if (!data.payload) {
            return;
        } 
        $scope.$apply(function() {

        });
    });
});
```

In my routs.js (Node.js) I am sending the following:
`socket.emit('medmart~procedure', procedure);`

However, I am not able to receive any messages in my controller. Can some one tell me what am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Tidy formatting, typo in title

Answer (score 0):

I was able to finally figure out the issue. Instead of

```
$scope.$on('procedure:new', function(data){...});
```

it should be:

```
mySocket.on('procedure:new', function(data){...});
```

I was able to resolve the issue by going through this demo:
https://github.com/btford/angular-socket-io-im